# C alphabetical dynamic allocation

Tags: c

i want to print this array of countries but when are two countries same i want to print it just once. countries are already ordered alphabeticaly any ides ???

```
for(b=0;b<v;b++){

if(strcmp(country[b-1],country[b]) !=0){
    printf("%s",country[b]);}

}
```

v is number of countries

Comment: `feof()` is almost surely wrong. And you forget to check *any* of the return values of your input functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Allocate a 2 dimensional character array dynamically for krajina.

Refer this question:
[2 Dimensional Memory Allocation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13304278/multi-dimensional-array-allocation)

EDIT: Elaboration:

Alright. You said you can count the number of countries. Say you store that in a variable called `count` ok?

Now you need to allocate a 2D character array with `count` number of rows and 31 columns right? You do this as follows.

```
int i = 0;
int **country = NULL;

if (!(country = calloc(count, sizeof(*country)))) //allocate rows
    return (0);
for (i = 0; i < count; i++)
{
    country[i] = calloc(31, sizeof(*(country[i]))); //allocate columns
}
```

Now you have the `country` variable which you can use normally like how you would use a 2d char array (like youve used in your code)

Comment: i dont know how can you please just tell me how it must look i am in hurry i must post it to school server till midnight and i have been working on that app for week and this is the online thing i dont know how to do

Comment: i done it is working but i found another problem when you have in file more countries with same name it will print them but i want just one i made for cycle but it is not working can you help me ?\

Comment: i pasted it at the end of questin

Comment: I recommend you sort the string array and print the elements and check whether previously printed string is different from current string before printing.  Btw, "upvote" the answer if it was useful. Press tick mark if it helped you solve the problem.

Comment: i made cycle but it is not working can you help me ?? i am totaly lost in it

Comment: yes its is sorted alphabeticaly only problem i have with printing it when there are two same countries in array i want to print just want it can be made by for cycle but i dont know how can you help me please i must send it to school  by hour

Comment: Are you getting any errors? And hey print the first country before that loop. Then set `b=1`. Because country[b-1] will refer to a garbage value in first iteration.